# On Linux, why does this library loaded with LD_PRELOAD catch only some openat() calls?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ld-preload

I am trying to intercept `openat()` calls with the following library `comm.c`. This is very standard minimal example, nothing special about it. I compile it with

```
>gcc -shared -Wall -fPIC -Wl,-init,init  comm.c -o comm.so
```

I am pasting this standard minimal example to show that, I thought, I knew what I was doing.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*openat_type)(int, const char *, int, ...);

static openat_type g_orig_openat;

void init() {
    g_orig_openat = (openat_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"openat");
}

int openat(int dirfd, const char* pathname, int flags, ...) {
    int fd;
    va_list ap;

    if (flags & (O_CREAT)) {
            va_start(ap, flags);
            fd = g_orig_openat(dirfd, pathname, flags, va_arg(ap, mode_t));
        }
    else
        fd = g_orig_openat(dirfd, pathname, flags);

    printf("openat dirfd %d pathname %s\n", dirfd, pathname);

    return fd;
}
```

I am running a `tar` command, again a minimal example, untarring an archive containing a single file `foobar`, to a pre-existing subdirectory `dir`:

```
>strace -f tar xf foobar.tar -C dir 2>&1 | grep openat
openat(AT_FDCWD, "dir", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(4, "foobar", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC, 0600) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
openat(4, "foobar", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC, 0600) = 5
```

However,

```
>LD_PRELOAD=./comm.so tar xf foobar.tar -C dir
openat dirfd 4 pathname foobar
openat dirfd 4 pathname foobar
```

OK, I know how to handle this - I have done this before - the reason for this kind of discrepancy, is that the system call `openat()` that is shown by `strace` is not done by the same-named user function `openat()`.  To find out what that other user function is, one gets the sources, rebuilds them, and finds out.

So, I got the sources for my `tar`:

```
>$(which tar) --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
```

I got the `tar` 1.26 sources and rebuilt them myself, and, lo and behold, if I use the binary `tar` that I built, rather than the above installed one, then `comm.so` does catch all 3 `openat` calls!

So that means there is no "other user function".

Please help, what is possibly going on here??

NO, the question is not answered by that previous question. That previous answer simply said, the library call may be differently named, than the underlying system call.  Here, that is NOT the case because I recompiled the same code myself, and there are no other library calls in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [intercepting the openat() system call for GNU tar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161116/intercepting-the-openat-system-call-for-gnu-tar)

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis no, thank you for the pointer, but the other question does not understand the difference between system calls and user calls, and how to diagnose them.  I think I do - please see the edit to clarify my point.

Comment: The difference between system calls and library calls has nothing to do with this, as the answer in the linked question indicates. The fact you're attempting to intercept an [alias](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/openat.c;h=9601e617dbd71d6474c1b28b255b706c20647b3e;hb=HEAD) does. I can put a complete answer together if you want.

Comment: Glibc may perform `openat` internally and it won't allow you to intercept those with `LD_PRELOAD` (calls in Glibc are not done through PLT).

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis then why does it work when I recompile the same code by myself??

Comment: @yugr can you elaborate, I have no idea what you are talking about. I tried to google-fu what you are saying and I came up with nothing of the sort.

Comment: Take a look e.g. at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7789619/2170527), it mentions that calls to standard functions inside Glibc (e.g. calls to `open` in `dlopen`) are non-interposable. That's a well-known Glibc trick to achieve higher performance.

Comment: @yugr OK thank you yes I got it, but, can you just tell me, how come, when I recompile the same `tar` code myself, then it works... It's the same code, there is no other 1.26 version.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis thank you, yes if you can explain the `alias` thing a little, I would appreciate - but I really want to know, is why it works when I recompile the same `tar` code myself.

Comment: It might be that in case of `tar` all `openat`s happen to be in user code whereas for the program some are done by Glibc.

Comment: @yugr no, no you don't understand - if I use the `tar` binary that is installed on my machine, the interception does not work, but if I recompile THE SAME code myself, then it does work. It's the same code, same version of `tar`, uses precisely the same `openat` calls, aliases, or whatever.

Comment: That's a good question but harder to answer without details (e.g. symbolized gdb stacktraces, for old and new `tar`s, for openat call which is not instrumented in original version of `tar`). I wonder if this may be related to [symbol versioning](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/symbol-versioning) i.e. `tar` uses older version of `openat`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the discussion mentioned, `openat` will probably be called by different symbol or function. The system call dumped by tool such as `strace` is raw system call. It might be wrapped by user function or glibc. If you want intercept it by LD_PRELOAD, you need to find out those wrapper instead of `openat`. To my experience, you can try intercept `open64` or `open`, it can redirect to `openat` which you observe on `strace`.

The [link](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c.html) is one example to wrap `openat` from `open64`.